# Change Parent Component State from Child functional component in React

Tags: reactjs

I've created a signing page component which contain sign-in component and sign-up component. My problem is how do I pass a onClick function from parent to child so as to change the state of my parent component(signing page component)? What I expect is that by clicking the button from child components so that the active state of the parent can be toggled and the style can be changed based on the active state. I am trying to pass a handleClick function from parent to child but it does not work well.

Any solutions?

Details in codesandbox:  https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-sanne-rf0u2?file=/src/components/SignIn/SignIn.js

In my parent component (SignPage),

```
function SignPage() {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
  const handleClick = () => {
    setActive(!active);
  };

return (
    <div className="sign-container">
      <div
        className={active ? "sign-wrapper s-signup" : "sign-wrapper"}
      >
        <SignIn handleClick={handleClick} />
        <SignUp handleClick={handleClick} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In my child components (SignIn / SignUp)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./SignIn.css";

function SignIn(handleClick) {
  return (
    <div className="sign-in-container">
      <form className="sign-form sign-in">
        <h2>Sign In</h2>
        <label htmlFor="email">
          <span>Email Address</span>
          <input type="email" name="email" />
        </label>
        <label htmlFor="password">
          <span>Password</span>
          <input type="password" name="password" />
        </label>
        <button className="submit" type="submit">
          Sign In
        </button>

        <p className="panel-switcher" onClick={handleClick()}>
          Don't have an account?
        </p>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SignIn;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, props are passed through as an object in the first parameter so for the `SignIn` component you can use destructuring so change to:

```js
function SignIn({ handleClick }) {
   // code...
   // Remove the () from `handleClick()` as that will immediately execute the function.
   <p className="panel-switcher" onClick={handleClick}>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, the `props` of component is **object** type.

So, if you wanna get the `handleClick` in child, it should be like below.

```js
function SignIn({ handleClick }) {
  // ...
}
```

Second, when handling over a function to child, it should not be called.

for example, like below.

```js
<p className="panel-switcher" onClick={handleClick}>
```